# Double Tap Parameter Configuration can not set from Internal Code

Tags: c++, movesense

I am writing code for the double-tap event but it's not working perfectly so I think that configuring the below internal registers might help to get better results:

1. doubleTapDur,
2. doubleTapQuiet,
3. tapThs,
4. axes

To set the value of the registers, I'm using ADB bridge via the Movesense showcase adb bridge app. here is the Link of the APK:[Showcaseapp-debug_adb-bridge-build.apk](https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-mobile-lib/downloads/Showcaseapp-debug_adb-bridge-build.apk)

I use the below command to read and write double-tap parameters. and it's working.

for read:

```
adb.exe shell am broadcast -a "android.intent.action.MOVESENSE"  --es type get --es path Component/LSM6DS3/TapParams --es value '''{}'''
```

for write:

```
 adb.exe shell am broadcast -a "android.intent.action.MOVESENSE"  --es type put --es path Component/LSM6DS3/TapParams --es value '''{\"newParams\":{\"doubleTapDur\": 8, \"doubleTapQuiet\": 3, \"tapThs\": 8, \"axes\": 8}}'''
```

To set these parameters internally (inside code), I wrote a function DoubleTAPConfig(), which sets the value in params. But it's not working. I am not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:-

```
#include "DOUBLETAP.h"
#include "common/core/debug.h"
#include "component_led/resources.h"
#include "component_lsm6ds3/resources.h"
#include "movesense.h"
#include "system_mode/resources.h"
#include "system_states/resources.h"
#include "ui_ind/resources.h"

const size_t BLINK_PERIOD_MS = 1000;
#define AVAILABILITY_TIME 5000

// LED blinking period in adertsing mode
#define LED_BLINKING_PERIOD 100

const char* const DOUBLETAP::LAUNCHABLE_NAME = "DOUBLETAP";



DOUBLETAP::DOUBLETAP()
    : ResourceClient(WBDEBUG_NAME(__FUNCTION__), WB_EXEC_CTX_APPLICATION),
      LaunchableModule(LAUNCHABLE_NAME, WB_EXEC_CTX_APPLICATION),
      DOUBLETAPEnabled(false),
      mTimer(wb::ID_INVALID_TIMER),
      mCounter(0)
{
}

DOUBLETAP::~DOUBLETAP()
{
}

bool DOUBLETAP::initModule()
{

    DEBUGLOG("DOUBLETAP::initModule");
    this->mModuleState = WB_RES::ModuleStateValues::INITIALIZED;

    return true;
}

void DOUBLETAP::deinitModule()
{
    DEBUGLOG("DOUBLETAP::deinitModule");
    this->mModuleState = WB_RES::ModuleStateValues::UNINITIALIZED;
}

bool DOUBLETAP::startModule()
{
    DEBUGLOG("DOUBLETAP::startModule");
    this->mModuleState = WB_RES::ModuleStateValues::STARTED;
    this->mTimer = startTimer(BLINK_PERIOD_MS, true); // Start LED timer. true = trigger repeatedly

    // set internal resistor value for doubletap mode
    DoubleTAPConfig();
    // Subscribe to DOUBLETAP detection
    this->asyncSubscribe(WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_STATES_STATEID(), AsyncRequestOptions::Empty, WB_RES::StateIdValues::DOUBLETAP);

    return true;
}

void DOUBLETAP::stopModule()
{
    DEBUGLOG("DOUBLETAP::stopModule");
    this->stopTimer(mTimer); // Stop LED timer
    this->mTimer = wb::ID_INVALID_TIMER;

    // Unsubscribe DOUBLETAP detection

    this->asyncUnsubscribe(WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_STATES_STATEID(), AsyncRequestOptions::Empty, WB_RES::StateIdValues::DOUBLETAP);

    this->mModuleState = WB_RES::ModuleStateValues::STOPPED;
}

void DOUBLETAP::onTimer(wb::TimerId timerId)
{

    if (DOUBLETAPEnabled)
    {
        this->asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::UI_IND_VISUAL(), AsyncRequestOptions::Empty, WB_RES::VisualIndTypeValues::SHORT_VISUAL_INDICATION);
        // break;
    }
    else
    {
        DOUBLETAPEnabled = false;
        // break;
    }
}

void DOUBLETAP::onNotify(wb::ResourceId resourceId, const wb::Value& value, const wb::ParameterList& parameters)
{

    DEBUGLOG("DOUBLETAP::onNotify");
    switch (resourceId.localResourceId)
    {

    case WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_STATES_STATEID::LID: {

        const WB_RES::StateChange& stateChange = value.convertTo<const WB_RES::StateChange&>();

        if (stateChange.stateId == WB_RES::StateIdValues::DOUBLETAP)
        {
            DEBUGLOG("Lead state updated. newState: %d", stateChange.newState);
            DOUBLETAPEnabled = !DOUBLETAPEnabled;
        }
    }
    }
}

void DOUBLETAP::DoubleTAPConfig()
{
    WB_RES::TapParams TapConfig;

    TapConfig.doubleTapDur = 8;   // set 0-15   Default:_ 0000
    TapConfig.doubleTapQuiet = 3; // set 0-3    Default value:_ 00
    TapConfig.tapThs = 8;         // set 0-31    Default value:_ 00000
    TapConfig.axes = 8;           // set 0-14   bitfield:_ x=8, y=4, z=2

    asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::COMPONENT_LSM6DS3_TAPPARAMS(), AsyncRequestOptions::Empty, TapConfig);
    
    // also try with this coomund line 
   // asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::COMPONENT_LSM6DS3_WAKEUP(),AsyncRequestOptions(NULL, 0, true), TapConfig);

}
```

I am not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "axes" - that's a fairly aggressive internal register. Maybe it'll help you, maybe you need to sharpen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /Component/LSM6DS3/TapParams -resource accessed the LSM6 chip registers directly, so in your firmware code the following happens:

1. You set the tap-params into the registers (DoubleTAPConfig method)
2. You start DOUBLE_TAP detection, which immediately resets the tap parameters in the registers to defaults

You'll need to:

1. first subscribe to the DOUBLE_TAP service
2. only when it's running (safest to wait until you receive the onSubscribeResult-callback with resultCode == 200), call the DoubleTAPConfig().

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: thank you so much your valuable response